# Parámetros de constructor

Tags: c++

Si la llamada en main de un constructor es la siguiente:

```
CRectangulo rect(x,y,dim,dim*2);
```

¿Como seria su declaración en su clase CRectangulo?
Necesito reconstruir un codigo y toda la información del constructor que me dan es su llamada en main.
He intentado algo como:

```
CRectangulo::CRectangulo(int&,int&,int&)
```

o

```
CRectangulo::CRectangulo(x,y,dim,dim*2)
```

Pero no hallo la solución con los argumentos que debo indicar.

Comment: Con lo que pones poco se puede hacer, replantea la pregunta y añade código suficiente para entender el problema... actualmente no tiene ni pies ni cabeza.

Comment: Te recomiendo que nos muestres un codigo de ejemplo, para poder reproducir el problema y asi poder ayudarte

Comment: Cierto  lo he editado,  espero que ahora sea suficiente.

Comment: @ElPatrón No sigue siendo suficiente ya que solo se agrego formato, lo que nos referimos es que agregues un poco mas de codigo, por ejemplo, agrega la clase `CRectangulo`, o agrega tu funcion `main()`

Comment: @ElPatrón debes agregar mas información, mas código fuente y explicación de lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 3):

Fíjate que la llamada recibe 4 argumentos luego el constructor tendrá que estar preparado para recibir, al menos, 4 variables:

```
CRectangulo::CRectangulo(int,int,int,int)
```

Las referencias de tu primera prueba `int&` dudo que sean necesarias en este caso. Eso solo sería necesario si las variables internas de `CRectangulo` deben apuntar a variables externas y eso es algo que pocas veces se requiere (y además es peligroso).

Comment: Lo probare muchas gracias!